# React Native AWS SDK

Tags: android, react-native, aws-sdk, aws-amplify, aws-sdk-js

I want to store my aws s3 access key id and secret key in my react native app. I am using it to upload files to my s3 bucket using presigned url. What is the best way to store this creds.

I stored it in env file and its exposed to all. I dont want this to be exposed to anyone. It must be very secret.

Comment: Use a backend server to handle AWS interactions. The server can store the credentials securely and generate pre-signed URLs for client-side use.